# Confusion about global variables in python

Tags: python, global-variables, python-import

I'm new to python, so please excuse what is probably a pretty dumb question.

Basically, I have a single global variable, called _debug, which is used to determine whether or not the script should output debugging information. My problem is, I can't set it in a different python script than the one that uses it.

I have two scripts:

```
one.py:
-------

def my_function():
  if _debug:
    print "debugging!"


two.py:
-------

from one import *
_debug = False

my_function()
```

Running two.py generates an error:

```
NameError: global name '_debug' is not defined
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are more problems than just the leading underscore I'm afraid.

When you call `my_function()`, it still won't have your `debug` variable in its namespace, unless you import it from `two.py`.

Of course, doing that means you'll end up with cyclic dependencies (`one.py -> two.py -> one.py`), and you'll get `NameError`s unless you refactor where various things are imported and declared.

One solution would be to create a simple third module which defines 'constants' like this, which can be safely imported from anywhere, e.g.:

```
constants.py
------------
debug = True

one.py
------
from constants import debug
#...

two.py
------
from constants import debug
#...
```

However, I would recommend just using the built in [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#module-logging) module for this - why not? It's easy to configure, simpler to use, reliable, flexible and extensible.

Comment: Yes, the logging module is the way to go here.

Answer (score 5):

Names beginning with an underscore aren't imported with

```
from one import *
```

Comment: And it is because they mean "this is internal stuff, do not touch it, or do so at your own risk".

Comment: I'm actually shocked that a completely incorrect answer has been accepted and voted up so highly.

Comment: Well it's not completely incorrect; kgiannakakis is correct about names beginning with underscores not being imported.  However, you're correct that this still isn't why his example code doesn't work.  Your answer is much better.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the `__debug__` variable for debugging. It is true if the interpreter wasn't started with the -O option. The assert statement might be helpful, too.

Answer (score 1):

A bit more explanation: The function `my_function`'s namespace is always in the module `one`. This means that when the name `_debug` is not found in `my_function`, it looks in `one`, not the namespace from which the function is called. Alabaster's answer provides a good solution.